# Android - Realm date day

Tags: java, android, realm

In SQLITE i had this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE LAST_REQUEST > date('now', '-1 day')
```

Is there some equivalent in Realm to get rows from 1 day or less?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well technically `java.util.Date` is a supported type in Realm, so you'd need to make a date of now and a date of the previous day, and use [between](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#between-java.lang.String-java.util.Date-java.util.Date-).

Like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48205516/2413303