# How to get data from **Realm database** using **date object**?

Tags: android, date, realm

I have tried some realm queries but not getting that result which I want

let's consider below table for example(Realm table):

```
id    Name  DateTimeStamp

1      A    2017-01-01 08:00:00
2      B    2017-01-01 15:00:00
3      C    2017-01-02 08:00:00
```

Now I want all those records which match the date "2017-01-01".so for this case I should get 2 records from realm table.Right now I am not getting any record.

For information "DateTimeStamp" column datatype is "Date".and yes I need to store date and time both in the database as you can see on the table.

Query i have tried is:

```
 long cnt = realm.where(ReservationObject.class).equalTo("DateTimeStamp",dateObject).count();
```

Please help me with this...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set up `Date` objects for `2017-01-01 00:00:00` and `2017-01-02 00:00:00` and query inbetween.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); // make sure month stays valid
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date jan1 = new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
Date jan2 = new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Then

```
realm.where(ReservationObject.class)
     .greaterThanOrEqualTo("DateTimeStamp", jan1)
     .lessThan("DateTimeStamp", jan2)
     .findAll()
```

Comment: it's working ...thank u..just edited your answer according to new version

Comment: this is way too complicated , realm should at least offer some date functions to query directly against the date object stored in table . Currently , out of no viable alternative ,   I had to use joda time api to work with any query involving   date and time processing . That include  simple query as  obtaining particular record retrieval meeting year ="YYYY" criteria !

Comment: Blame the calendar api :p

Comment: Don't just  blame java.util.Date object , try to offer the most commonly used  date functions found in the standard SQL date  query  !

Comment: The core query parser supports time in format of `"time > 2017-12-1@12:07:53"` (GMT) but due to core query parser making Realm much larger, raw query support is not included in Realm-Java 5.0. So that's why you use a Date to set up the query instead.

Comment: That the reason why Realm can not use on app to store real time date sensitive data records manipulation!

Comment: what about pure JNI call to C real  date function using c++ pointer concept  , time.h ??

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: minutes hours seconds must be 00:00:00?

Comment: Milliseconds must also be 000.

Answer (score 0):

Use `contains` it work like LIKE

```
long cnt =
 realm.where(ReservationObject.class)
 .contains("DateTimeStamp",dateObject).count();
```

OR Latest version have

```
public RealmQuery<E> like(String fieldName,
                      String value,
                      Case casing)
```

Comment: i think contains will not going to work with date object

Comment: what about like?

Comment: It's a `Date` field, not `String`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce exaclty it's date field