# How do I count the number of entries per date in a Realm database?

Tags: android, database, realm

I have a bit of an issue. I have a realm database where each entry has an **ID** and a **DateCreated**. I'm going to display these in a chart, which can filter between ranges such as Last Week, Last Month, and Last Year.

Basically, I would like to know how to be able to count the number of entries per distinct day in order to display them in a line chart. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in your case is use the ability of Realm (since Realm 0.88.0) to use a setter and modify multiple other fields within the RealmObject. That way you can have separate fields for data along with `dateCreated` so that you don't need to do [what this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205164/how-to-get-data-from-realm-database-using-date-object).

```
public class MyClass extends RealmObject {
    @Index
    private long createdDay;
    @Index
    private long createdMonth;
    @Index
    private long createdYear;

    @Index
    private Date createdDate;

    public void setCreatedDate(Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // Calendar is 0...11
        this.createdMonth = month;
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        this.createdDay = day;
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        this.createdYear = year;

        this.createdDate = date;
    }
}
```

With this class now you can do

```
realm.where(MyClass.class).equalTo("createdYear", 2018) // for year

realm.where(MyClass.class).equalTo("createdYear", 2018)
                          .equalTo("createdMonth", 1) // for month


realm.where(MyClass.class).equalTo("createdYear", 2018)
                          .equalTo("createdMonth", 1)
                          .equalTo("createdDay", 12) // for day
```

And you'll get the objects that were created in 2018, instead of having to create a Date from `2018-01-01@00:00:00.000` to `2018-12-31@23:59:59.999`.

---

But of course, creating the Date would work too, with using [getActualMinimum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum(int)) and [getActualMaximum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum(int)).

**EDIT:**

Actually, your case might even be simpler than what I said above, because you'd just need:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
Date lastWeek = calendar.getDate();

RealmResults<MyClass> results = realm.where(MyClass.class)
                                  .greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdDate", lastWeek)
                                  .findAll();
```

Comment: your edit was one of the things i was looking for, thank you, however what should I do if i want to get the number of *entries* created per distinct day per week/month?

Comment: I think that's when you might want to use what I wrote initially and then do `count()` on those queries.